# Getting Window function to assign variable locally

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, scope

I am trying to get my Angular2 service to use the LinkedIN javascript SDK that is loaded by the script linkedin provides. the functionality works for getting  the data and returning it but I can't set the local function variable to the data I got back from linkeidn

```
export class LinkedInAuthService {

constructor(

) {

}

linkedInAuthorization() {
    window['IN'].User.authorize();
    window['IN'].Event.on(window['IN'], 'auth', this.getLinkedInUserInfo);
}
getLinkedInUserInfo() {
    let linkedinInfo:any;
    window['IN']
        .API
        .Raw()
        .url("/people/~:(firstName,lastName,emailAddress,industry,specialties,positions)?format=json")
        .result(function(data:any){
            console.log(data) //logs data correctly
            linkedinInfo = data 
        });
    console.log(linkedinInfo) // undefined
}

AuthLinkedInUserforGlx() {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('linkedinInfo'))
}
}
```

I think the problem is when I set `linkedinInfo = data` it is not setting it locally, just not sure how to make it local

Comment: "data:any" is this a typo?

Comment: @Darkrum nope that is not causing the problem

Comment: im curios then what does the : do?

Comment: its typescript for type. @Darkrum

Comment: bah... Should have read the tags.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
export class LinkedInService {
IN = window['IN'];
userProfile: Object;
constructor() {
    this.userProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'))
    this.IN.Event.on(this.IN, 'auth', this.getLinkedInUserInfo);
    console.log('end of constructor')
}

linkedInAuthorization(){
    this.IN.User.authorize();
    console.log('end of linkedInAuthorization service')
}

getLinkedInUserInfo() {
    this.IN.API.Raw()
        .url("/people/~:(firstName,lastName,emailAddress,industry,specialties,positions)?format=json")
        .result((data:any) => {
            localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(data));
            this.userProfile = data;
        });
    console.log('end of getLinkedInUserInfo service');
    this.AuthLinkedInOnGlx
}

AuthLinkedInOnGlx (){

}



}
```